# Cups dependency error in Raspbian

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, cups

I have been trying to configure my raspberry in order to have a printer server. I have a Hp printer which is connected through USB to my raspberry pi.
The first part of this project is to configure printer with the RPi, and every website (also here) I found indicate that is needed to install cups using `apt-get`.

The point is that I have dependency errors, I haven't been able to solve it.

**What I have try:**

1. Remove and install again: I remove all packages of cups and then try to install it.
2. I have made `sudo apt-get update && upgrade` (I lost the count of times I have repeat it).
3. I upgrade the OS: I was working in Raspbian Wheezy and I upgrade to Raspbian Jessie.

How could I go on with this?

I have not try to clear my sd and start from another Raspbian installation from nothing, because I use my RPi to control another stuff in my home, so I prefer not to go ahead this solution if there is any other chance to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Welcome to U&L , [please edit your question here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/404208/edit) . Add the error to your question ,also the `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` and `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*`

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I will edit today, tonight whem I arrived home.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command:

```
sudo apt-cache show cups | grep -i dep
```

Gives these dependencies:

```
libavahi-client3 (>= 0.6.16)
libavahi-common3 (>= 0.6.16)
libc6 (>= 2.16)
libcups2 (= 2.1.3-4)
libcupscgi1 (>= 1.4.2)
libcupsimage2 (>= 1.4.0)
libcupsmime1 (>= 1.4.0)
libcupsppdc1 (>= 1.4.0)
libgcc1 (>= 1:3.5)
libstdc++6 (>= 4.3.0)
libusb-1.0-0 (>= 2:1.0.8)
debconf (>= 1.2.9)
debconf-2.0, libc-bin (>= 2.13)
cups-core-drivers (>= 2.1.3-4)
cups-daemon (>= 2.1.3-4)
poppler-utils (>= 0.12)
procps
ghostscript (>= 9.02~)
lsb-base (>= 3.2-14~)
cups-common (>= 2.1.3-4)
cups-server-common (>= 2.1.3-4)
cups-client (>= 2.1.3-4)
cups-ppdc
cups-filters (>= 1.0.24-3~)
```

Maybe you could try installing these?
Hope this works.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. When I try this, I will give more information about which of this packages are the ones that return this dependency error.

Comment: Sorry I haven't posted. Really thanks for your answer. I finally achieve this to work with that dependencies. Now I am having troubles with hplip, but I am currently solving it, thank you.

Comment: Glad to be of help! Could you give me a plus one?

Comment: I tried, but I cannot cause I am nobbie and have less than 15 reputation :(